# Symfony Form Builder using Doctrine Proxies instead of Entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine, formbuilder

I was wondering why my CollectionType doesn't call the custom addCollection function that sets the foreign key to $this (and thus the next time the collection is empty).

Then i found out about 'by_reference' but it didn't fix the problem but instead made it worse.

in the form i simply do:

```php
$builder->add('myprop', CollectionType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'entry_type' => MyEntityType::class,
            'entry_options' => [
                'label' => false,
                'new' => $new,
            ],
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false, // instead of not calling add it now throws an error
        ]);
```

and the MyEntityType is just another type with data_class set and fields for it

It seems it is using the Doctrine Proxies instead of my Entity i pass into the FormBuilder as i get the error message:

> Could not determine access type for property "myprop" in class "Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\MyEntity": Neither the property "myprop" nor one of the methods "addMyprop()"/"removeMyprop()", "addMyprop()"/"removeMyprop()", "setMyprop()", "Myprop()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\MyEntity".

using newest Symfony 4.3 (4.3.5)

Comment: also this happens with EntityTypes as well it seems

Comment: so how does your `MyEntity` handle `myprop`? are there setters/getters? are they public? is it a  public property?

Comment: @Jakumi yes it got get/add/remove functions generated from symfony make:entity command, like add function sets the foreign key to this for example (and it not being called is how i found out about this issue)

Comment: ok i found out that this issue has to do with FormType nesting as the first level has the right entity type and the following childs only got the Proxies

Comment: you should not worry about the proxy objects. they should behave exactly like proper entity objects.

Comment: @Jakumi thats not true. why else would i get errors then?

Comment: it's usually something different that's causing the error. the proxy objects actually have all the same methods the original has (signature-wise), so if your entity has one the functions, so should the proxy object. so the error message should apply to both the proxy object and the entity

Comment: you can try to clear the caches and see if that helps ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not in the FormBuilder but instead in the Entity as it was imported using plural names and the Symfony name generator tried to call the singular method but only the plural one existed...